# Using a wildcard to replace CSV cell contents with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, wildcard

I'm trying to get PowerShell to manipulate some CSV data.

The column I’m trying to manipulate in my CSV contains stock levels as text, containing mostly "High", "Good", "Medium", "Low" and "Out Of Stock" which I want to convert to a numerical format before importing the CSV to the website at the end of the day.

My code currently is:

```
#Declare Stock Level Words To Value
$StockLevelWordToValue = @{
    "High" = "70"
    "Good" = "50"
    "Medium" = "30"
    "Low" = "10"
    "Out Of Stock" = "0"
}

# import the CSV file
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\temp\temp.csv";

# for each row, replace the Stock Level Word field with a value
foreach($row in $csv) {
    $row."Stock Level" = $StockLevelWordToValue[$row."Stock Level"];
}

# export the modified CSV
$csv | Export-Csv "C:\temp\temp2.csv" -NoTypeInformation;
```

The problem I have is in my "Stock Level" column, some of the entries are like "Good: Last update August 2019" or “High: Last update March 2019”

Currently, when running this code, there is no value returned for these entries and the cell is blank.

I was hoping a wildcard would work like:

```
"Good*" = "50"
```

But that returns a blank cell too.

How can check a cell "contains" a word and returns a numerical value, no matter what other words are in that cell?

Comment: you have a good start. [*grin*] however, you cannot use wildcards like that with lookup tables [hashtables]. instead, parse your CSV column value to prune it back to just the key. it looks like you could use `.Split(':')[0].Trim()` to get just the part that matches your lookup key values.

Comment: Thanks Lee, that's (kinda) what I've done.

So, I realised if I trim the character length down I can end up with 5 consistent values for the stock level column.

I've trimmed it down to 3 characters, so I end up with "Hig", "Goo", "Med", "Low" or "Out" - then it doesn't matter about any date added afterwards.

And then run the above script to change that to an equivalent value.

Comment: neato! glad to know you got it working as needed ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select-String` to check the value of your attribute by patterns like "High*". This will return null if doesn't find any, true if there is a string matching this pattern.

```
foreach($row in $csv) {
     If ($row."Stock Level" | Select-String "High*) {
          $row."Stock Level" = $StockLevelWordToValue["High"];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Erick, that’s a neat way to do it and good to know for the future. 